# When changing the names of columns in a table through the use of SQL via python, the name change does not occur

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a reference table that contains columns "OldColumnName" and "NewColumnName".
"OldColumnName" refers to an existing column name (most of the time) in the table, "NewColumnName" is the name I'm trying to change it to.

Here's what my code looks like:

```py
# Returns a list of lists e.g., ((OldColName1, NewColName1), (OldColName2,NewColName2))
oldNewColList = conn.execute("SELECT OldColumnName, NewColumnName FROM ColumnNamesRef").fetchall()
for colName in oldNewColList:
    try:
        conn.execute("EXEC sp_RENAME '["+str(table[0])+"_New].["+str(colName[0])+"]', '"+str(colName[1])+"', 'COLUMN'")
    except ProgrammingError as e:
        if '42000' in str(e):
            pass
        else:
            raise Exception("Error not accounted for: "+str(e))
```

The reason for the try and catch is for this error:

> (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong. (15248) (SQLExecDirectW)')
> [SQL: EXEC sp_RENAME '[Insureds_New].[FLAGS00]', 'ADDRESS2SUBSTITUTE', 'COLUMN']

I looked and found out that the column did, in fact, not exist and if that's the case then nothing needs to be done and I can continue. After accounting for the error, I thought all was good, however, when that code runs the name changes do not actually take place.

I can see that the name change gets rolled back if the column doesn't exist in the table, but if the column DOES exist in the table, no COMMIT takes place.

Column that does not exist:

> 2023-02-17 13:49:07,778 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine EXEC sp_RENAME '[Insureds_New].[FLAGS00]', 'ADDRESS2SUBSTITUTE', 'COLUMN'
> 2023-02-17 13:49:07,779 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
> 2023-02-17 13:49:07,815 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK

Column that does exist:

> 2023-02-17 13:49:07,854 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine EXEC sp_RENAME '[Insureds_New].[FLAGS01]', 'SHORTTERM', 'COLUMN'
> 2023-02-17 13:49:07,856 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()

Answer (score 0):

You must commit your transaction throug `conn.commit()` method or `conn.cursor.commit()`!

Comment: When trying I receive ```Connection' object has no attribute 'commit'```

Comment: so you must get the cursor, something like `conn.cursor.commit()`

Comment: I feel like you're right, but the ```conn.cursor.commit()``` isn't working either... ```'Connection' object has no attribute 'cursor'```